# How do I add an UpdatePanel and its trigger programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I'm adding a variable number of update panels in Page_Init.

I already have a script manager in my master page.

The problem is that when I try to add a trigger like:

```
AsyncPostBackTrigger trig2 = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();

trig2.ControlID = ddl22.UniqueID;

trig2.EventName = "SelectedIndexChanged";

up2.Triggers.Add(trig2);
```

where ddl22 is a DropDownList, the event never seems to trigger the UpdatePanel.

In the UpdatePanel I have another DropDownList the data of which i want to change when the trigger happens.

The funny thing is that in the master page I have a timer.  This timer is only supposed to trigger the UpdatePanel in the master but it seems to trigger all of my update panels.  However, even when it triggers the update panel in the child page, the second DropDownList does not change its data.

The data is databound to the DropDownList in the UpdatePanel in page_init. It is bound to an objectdatasource which uses the selected item in the first DropDownList as a parameter to determine what data it should bind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set `AutoPostBack="True"` for your drop down list? I suspect this is the issue.

Also set your update panel mode to conditional-`UpdateMode="Conditional"` so that i does not affect other update panels.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

In Source Code,

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>    
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl2_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
      <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="ddl2" />
  </Triggers>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually call the UpdatePanel to refresh without specifying a trigger on a postBack event. Firstly, `set the UpdateMode property to 'Conditional'`, then you can just call an update on your updatepanel from code behind like

```
MyUpdatePanel.Update();
```